# Could a Torah Scroll Be Writtin in Ktav Ivri (Paleo Hebrew)?

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah, safrus, kedusha-holiness

> The Talmud (ibid) brings different opinions about the origin of the two in regards to how was the Torah initially written.
>
> It is agreed by all that the language has remained the same, Hebrew – as we know it today,
> It is similarly agreed that today we use only the Ktav Ashuri and the Ktav Ivri contains no sanctity. (Yadaim 4, 5; Megilah 8b; Rashi ibid)

Source: http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=2626

It is brought down that we now use Ktav Ashuri and all of our Torah scrolls, tefillin, and mezuzot, and that this was instituted by Ezra. But if a sofer were to write a Torah in Paleo Hebrew (like as found in the Dead Sea Scrolls), what would the status of such a scroll be? Would the scroll be permitted for use? Would it have kedusha?

Comment: "It is brought down that we now use Ktav Ashuri and all of our Torah scrolls, tefillin, and mezuzot, and that this was instituted by Ezra." Where is this brought down?

Comment: near dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62564/759

Answer (score 7):

In [Massechet Mezuzah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_tractate) [1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Mezuzah.1.3?lang=bi), we read:

> שנה אותיותיה או שנכתבה עברית הרי זו פסולה.
>
> If you changed [a mezuzah]'s letters or it was written in *k'tav ivri*, it is *pasul*. [my transl.]

The same can be found in [Massechet Tefillin 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Tefillin.1.2?lang=bi).

Your source in the OP brings [Mishnah Yadayim 4:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yadayim.4.5?lang=bi), in which we read:

> ‮תַּרְגּוּם שֶׁכְּתָבוֹ עִבְרִית וְעִבְרִית שֶׁכְּתָבוֹ תַּרְגּוּם, וּכְתָב עִבְרִי, אֵינוֹ מְטַמֵּא אֶת הַיָּדַיִם. לְעוֹלָם אֵינוֹ מְטַמֵּא, עַד שֶׁיִּכְתְּבֶנּוּ אַשּׁוּרִית, עַל הָעוֹר, וּבִדְיוֹ.
>
> If an Aramaic section was written in Hebrew, or a Hebrew section was written in Aramaic, or [Hebrew which was written with] *k'tav ivri*, it does not defile the hands. It never defiles the hands until it is written in the Assyrian script, on parchment, and in ink. [transl. lightly edited from Sefaria]

["Defilement of the hands"](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9) was decreed on scrolls so as to save them from being destroyed by mice that were also eating *terumah* ([Shabbat 14a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.14a.7?lang=bi)) or so that they wouldn't be used as carpets for animals ([Tosefta Yadayim 2:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Yadayim.2.9?lang=bi)).

Rambam rules in [Mishne Torah Shabbat 23:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbath.23.26?lang=bi) that only writings in *k'tav ashuri* may be saved from a fire on Shabbat:

> ... וְהוּא שֶׁיִּהְיוּ כְּתוּבִין אַשּׁוּרִית ...
>
> ... And that is when they were written in Assyrian script ... [transl. from Sefaria]

To put these sources together: scrolls written in *k'tav ivri* are disqualified from use, and even not considered to have *kedusha*, since we don't worry about them being destroyed or used in an inappropriate manner.

(I got most of these sources from Rav Menachem Kasher's [Torah Shleyma vol. 29](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51444&st=&pgnum=34). See there for *many* more details and some possible nuance according to some [potentially rejected] opinions.)