# Can items for the Temple Be Written in Ivri?

Tags: halacha, beis-hamikdash, writing-printing

The halakha is that scrolls of the Torah, mezuzot, and parchments for tefillin must be written in Ashuri. But what about items used for the Temple Service? Such as the tzitz (crown that the Kohen wears) or the writing on the breastplate?

Comment: Do you mean like the parsha of Sotah? What other things for the Temple service requiring writing did you have in mind?

Comment: You sort of already asked this https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62564/759 @david tzitz or avnei hachoshen/ephod